# WebStorm wraps text not as expected

Tags: webstorm

How can I configure WebStorm so that it wraps text near the restriction line but not at the window corner?

[image]

Comment: Well ... the right margin (that vertical line) -- you can configure your Code Style to tell IDE to wrap the code (*split it into "real" multiple lines*) -- it will be used on code reformatting. Right now what you are seeing on a screen is *virtual wrap* -- it does not add any line breaks there -- it is just to allow you to see long lines without the need to scroll it horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no native setting that can enable this directly.

However, someone wrote a plugin for this : [WrapToColumn](https://github.com/abrookins/WrapToColumn).